# gradlew is not found in when building android application tests in CircleCI

Tags: android, gradle, circleci

I have an android project that i would like to build and test by deploying in CircleCI 2.0.

When performing the build, I get the error

```
*$#!bin/bash -eo pipefail
.gradlew androidDependencies
/bin/bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory
Exited with Code 127*

version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/AndroidDemo
    docker:
      # Android the primary container
      - image: circleci/android:api-25-alpha
environment:
  JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
steps:
  - checkout
  #- restore_cache:
  #    key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
  - run:
      name: Download Dependencies
      command: ./gradlew androidDependencies
 # - save_cache:
  #    paths:
   #     - ~/.gradle
   #   key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}

  #- run:
  #    name: Run UnitTest
  #    command: ./gradlew testDemoDebugUnitTest
  - run:
      name: Setup emulator
      command: sdkmanager "system-images;android-24;default;armeabi-v7a" && echo "no" | avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-24;default;armeabi-v7a"
  - run:
      name: Launch emulator
      command: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64/qt/lib && emulator64-arm -avd test -noaudio -no-boot-anim -no-window -accel auto -verbose
      background: true
  - run:
      name: Wait emulator
      command: |
        # wait for it to have booted
        circle-android wait-for-boot
        # unlock the emulator screen
        sleep 30
        adb shell input keyevent 82
  - run:
      name: Run EspressoTests
      command: ./gradlew connectedDemoDebugAndroidTest
  - store_artifacts:
      path: app/build/reports
      destination: reports
  - store_test_results:
      path: app/build/test-results
```

I have set the working directory in my config.yml file

// AndroidDemo is where my project resides

working_directory: ~/AndroidDemo

Comment: Post your `config.yml`. Also, you should not have to set a working directory.

Comment: @JaredBurrows uploaded it.

Comment: @SnehPandya, thanks for the edit

Comment: Try removing that working directory, you should not need to use it. Circle should do a git clone, then run gradlew. Another easy way to debug would be to do an "ls" and a "pwd" on the build server to see where you are at.

Comment: @SheikhFaisalMiskhat : did you get any success? I'm facing the same issue?

Comment: @Kushal I followed Jared's comment. It actually helped me to identify and solve the problem.

Comment: @SheikhFaisalMiskhat okay.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried refactoring the config file and moved to Circle CI 2.0 since 1.0 isn't supported.

The circle.yml file should be put under the root directory that CircleCI should clone.

permissions should be granted to gradlew.

```
chmod +x gradlew
```

under **test:** execute gradlew as follows:

```
./gradlew -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.android_demo.MyTestsTestSuite connectedAndroidTest -PdisablePreDex
```

This worked for me.